# How to aquire text from a webserver and show it depending on region

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there a way to extract the text from a website (That only has text and can be updated by the webserver) and put it in a text view or string variable so that it will show the text in my android app.

Also, there are different languages based on what region your phone is in (English being the default).

This is what I've been using so far

```
    public String getText(String uri) {
    HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        String response_str = client1.execute(request, responseHandler);
        return response_str;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";

    }
```

Unfortunately I haven't figured out a way to get rid of the html code or how to change the website being passed in depending on the region. Thanks

Comment: are you getting a response from the server? If so, could you post it? I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence - what html code?

Comment: i'm pulling from a website like this http://www.cellphonesolutions.net/welcome-en that has all text but also includes the html text such as header and body and color. Displayed on my app should just be the text in the appropriate spots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very simple function that I use to make my code look cleaner.

```
    public String getText(String uri) {
    HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        String response_str = client1.execute(request, responseHandler);
        return response_str;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the html header, body color, etc keeps a static format (such as always ending in `<br>`), you can use the [`split(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method in the `String` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there a function or method out there that can translate the html code so that the words in between <title></title> gets set to the title of an alert dialog etc...

Comment: You can use Java's HTML parser: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/Parser.html